# Apache, PHP, "I/O warning : failed to load external entity" sometimes

Tags: php, apache-2.4

I'm trying to install [CDash](http://www.cdash.org/) at VPS. Usually it works great for a while after apache is restarted, but after few minutes it starts failing randomly with following errors:

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/cdash/footer.xsl" in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /cdash/ line 4 element include in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:include : unable to load /cdash/footer.xsl in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/cdash/local/footer.xsl" in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /cdash/ line 5 element include in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:include : unable to load /cdash/local/footer.xsl in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/cdash/headscripts.xsl" in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /cdash/ line 6 element include in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:include : unable to load /cdash/headscripts.xsl in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/cdash/local/headscripts.xsl" in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): compilation error: file /cdash/ line 7 element include in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:include : unable to load /cdash/local/headscripts.xsl in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 55
Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): No stylesheet associated to this object in /cdash/cdash/common.php on line 65
```

I'm using Ubuntu Server 13.10. I've tried CDash 2.0.2 and latest version from svn trunk with the same result.

Comment: The error looks obvious. What have you already done to solve it?

Comment: I've double-checked if these files really exist and if they have appropriate access rights. I've also checked if my apache configuration is updated for apache-2.4 (Yes, it is). Could you please point me out this obvious thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved that by adding `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);` at the beginning of `cdash/common.php` file.
Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534866/intermittent-simplexml-load-file-i-o-warning-on-local-joomla-site